# How to set report with tracking history (custom object)?

Tags: custom-object, history-tracking

power SalesForce friends,

currently I'm struggling with reporting changes - checkbox field.
I need to get information: if it was changed/when it was changed.

My Custom object has tracking history field mode on. This field what needed to be reported is one of few which has set tracking.

I want to create report which will tell me now, which records has been updated-when. Like it was with Opportunity History - last stage/next stage/date and so on...
What do you think? This is possible to have?
Many thx for your attention and help.

Best regards,
Michał

Answer (score 1):

If your custom object is the detail object in a master-detail relationship, you cannot currently use field history reports. If you custom object is NOT in this type of relationship, when you turn on 'Enable reports' and 'Field Tracking', a  History report type should be created automatically.